# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: How to set JAVA_HOME path for flutter?

Tags: flutter, path, java-home

I am trying to install flutter at my window 10.
but i hava problems like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyP26.png)

I googled it for 10 days, i reinstall java and set the path of java ..

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
```

```
%PATH%;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
C:\Users\82109\Flutte;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Roaming;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Roaming\.dart;
C:\tools\flutter;C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;C:\tools\dart-sdk;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\flutter;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Local\Temp\dart-sdk;
C:\Users\82109\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter;
C:\tools\flutter\bin;C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe;
C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin;
C:\tools\flutter\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin
```

[System variables setting for path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bTkt.png)

[System variables setting for JAVA_HOME]

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
```

BUT there are still problem that JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory
how can i do? i already reinstall java about 3~4 times then check the path of java folder....
how can i fix this problems?